# calculate in redshift the week number of the year as weeknum() in excel

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, week-number

I need to calculate in redhsift sql the week number of the year starting from sunday to saturday and starting with the first of January but truncating the first week after the occurence of the first saturday.
Kinda like WEEKNUM() works in excel:

so for example in 2020 it will be (mm/dd/yyyy)

- 01/01/2020 -> weeknum = 1
- ...
- 01/04/2020 -> weeknum = 1
- 01/05/2020 -> weeknum = 2
- ...
- 01/11/2020 -> weeknum = 2
- 01/12/2020 -> weeknum = 3

while:

- 12/31/2019 -> weeknum = "last weeknum of the 2019"

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This gives a week number that AFAICT follows the behavior of Excel and MSSQL:

- weeks are sunday-saturday
- first day of the year is always week 1
- first/last days of the year are not necessarily full weeks

```sql
case when to_char(date_trunc('year', some_date), 'iw') = '01'
     then to_char(some_date + '1 day'::interval, 'iw')
     else to_char(some_date + '8 days'::interval, 'iw')
end
```